# SparkAR Dynamic instantiation doesn't work at all

Tags: augmented-reality, spark-ar-studio

Even sample code @ https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/scripting/dynamic-instantiation completely doesn't work. Can't open the example project either (tried copy pasting code to a new project with same objects and still no success). Anyone else having the same issue?

When I use Scene.create there is no notification saying there are dynamic object and to switch to dynamic mode

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check option in menu Project -> Edir Properties -> Capabilities -> slick + sing -> search for "Script Dynamic Instantiation"

[image]

Comment: duuuude thanks so much I totally gave up haha how do I mark this as the answer? (stack noob sorry :P)