# Spark AR - Can't create an Scene Object with Scene.create() method

Tags: javascript, spark-ar-studio

My code is below, I'm getting a warning in console
`Possible unhandled promise rejection: Typeerror: undefined is not a function`

The error trace will always point to `Scene.create()` method, even though according to the docs, is a valid call

https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/scenemodule#methods

```js
const Scene = require('Scene');
const D = require('Diagnostics');

(async function () {
  const sprites = [];

  for (const i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const dynamicSprite = await Scene.create("PlanarImage", {
        "name": `sprite${i}`,
        "width": 0.1,
        "height": 0.1,
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "hidden": true,
        'material' : 'material1'
    });

    sprites.push(dynamicSprite );
  }
})();
```

Things I checked:

- that there is no other object with the same name
- that I'm typing the class name correctly:
  https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/reference/classes/scenemodule.planarimage
- that there is a material1 in the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with this answer
[SparkAR Dynamic instantiation doesn't work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327172/sparkar-dynamic-instantiation-doesnt-work-at-all)

Had to enable dynamic instantation in the project.